# FRITZ!Box Samba share works using smbclient but not CIFS

Tags: samba, cifs, fritzbox, smbclient

I am trying to mount a disk attached to my FRITZ!box router NAS on my Manjaro Linux. FRITZ!box OS only supports SMBv1.0 at the moment, so I need to force the old protocol.

The following commandline works:

```
$ smbclient -L //astronautenband/Astronautenbande --option='client min protocol=NT1'
Enter WORKGROUP\phistep's password: 
Anonymous login successful

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    Astronautenbande Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Astronautenbande)
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.
Anonymous login successful

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    WORKGROUP            ASTRONAUTENBANDE
```

while this gives me a strange error

```
# mount -v -t cifs //astronautenband/Astronautenbande /mnt/Astronautenbande/ \
    -o username=phistep,password=<pw>,vers=1.0
mount error: could not resolve address for astronautenband: Unknown error
```

Ultimately I want to mount on boot using `/etc/fstab` (probably using a credential file instead of verbatim password)

```
//ASTRONAUTENBAND/Astronatautenbande/Storage/Back_In_Time /mnt/Astronautenbande cifs _netdev,nofail,username=phistep,password=pw> 0 0
```